# Break Promise execution inside an async function - JS

Tags: javascript

I've the next async function:

```
  private _activateProgressBar(): void {
      (async () => {
        await this.check(1000);
        await this.check(3000);
        await this.check(5000);
        this.modalClose('success');
      })();
  }
```

Inside my `check` function, i'd like to check some condition and according to that decide if i'd like to continue to the next Promise after a certain time or stop the execution:

```
  check(ms: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.condtion) {
        return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
      } else {
         reject();
      }
    }).catch(null);
  }
```

As you can see here I'm returning `Promise.reject();`, but apparently it's not preventing to move to the next `Promise`.
How can i stop the progress to the next `Promise` in this case and stop the sequence?

Comment: dont return `Promise.reject()`, call the `reject` function.

Comment: You can return some boolean from the `check` method and using the return value, you can decide if you want to continue or skip.

Answer (score 1):

The value you return from the callback to you pass to the `Promise` constructor is irrelevant.

This means that creating a second, but rejected, promise and then returning it is pointless. It will just be discarded.

If you want to reject the promise then call the `reject` function it gives you.

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                             ^^^^^^
```

Comment: something like that? because it's not stopping it
```check(ms: number): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.condition) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        return reject();
      });
    }
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    });
  }```

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to return some boolean from `check` method and based on the return value, you can decide if you want to execute further or not.

```
check(ms: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (this.condtion) {
        return setTimeout(() => {
             resolve(true);
        }, ms);
      } else {
         resole(false);
      }
    }).catch(null);
  } 

private _activateProgressBar(): void {
      (async () => {
        let proceed = true;
        if(proceed) {
          proceed = await this.check(1000);
        }

        if(proceed) {
          proceed = await this.check(3000);
        }


        if(proceed) {
          proceed = await this.check(5000);
        }
        
        this.modalClose('success');
      })();
  }
```

This just and example, you can make it more generic and optimized. Just trying to reuse your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `try/catch` block around all your `await`, the first to fail will halt the execution and be caught in the `catch`. Simply `reject()` the Promise.

```
(async () => {
    try {
        await this.check(1000);
        await this.check(3000); // If this one fails...
        await this.check(5000); // ...this one won't be reached...
        this.modalClose('success'); // ...this won't be triggered...
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("One of them failed") // and you'll get here instead.
    }
})();

check(ms: number): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (this.condtion) {
            return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
        } else {
            reject();
        }
    })
}
```

Edit : demo (adapted TS into JS so it runs inside a snippet)

```js
const check = ms => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (ms !== 3000) {
      return setTimeout(resolve, ms);
    } else {
      reject();
    }
  })
}

(async() => {
  try {
    await check(1000);
    await check(3000); // If this one fails...
    console.log("You shouldn't see me!") // ...you won't see this...
    await check(5000); // ...this one won't be reached...
    this.modalClose('success'); // ...this won't be triggered...
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("One of them failed") // and you'll get here instead.
  }
})();
```